# VBA - help on debugging copy/paste that's gone wrong

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

Something mysterious happens in a small part of my code, and I can't figure out what's wrong.
This is the problem-bit (and I've skipped the sheet/report-definitions that I have at the top):

```
Set FoundRow = sh_NYlandsum.Columns(1).Find("SUM", lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)
    FoundRow.Offset(, 1).Resize(1, 33).Copy
        sh_Data3.Range("C" & sh_Data3.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

Set wb_rapp = Workbooks.Open(fPath & "\R2\" & "Gruppe1.xls")   
    FoundRow = wb_rapp.Sheets(1).Range("A1:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Find("SUM", Cells(1, 1), MatchCase:=True).Row
    Range("S" & FoundRow & ":AE" & FoundRow).Copy
FoundRow = sh_SumGrupper.Range("A1:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Find("G1", Cells(1, 1)).Row    
sh_SumGrupper.Range("B" & FoundRow & ":N" & FoundRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
wb_rapp.Close False
```

I've been debugging the code using F8, and this is what's happening:

First bit goes to sheet NYlandsum (ThisWB), finds word "SUM" in row A, and copies columns B-AH. Data is passed into sheet "Data3" (ThisWB) columns C:AI (first available row).
Works just fine.

Next bit opens up a report, finds word "SUM" in row A, and copies columns S-AE. Data is passed into sheet "SumGrupper" (ThisWB), where it finds row holding "G1" in column A, and puts data into columns B:N.
Works just fine.

BUT..., when this last bit is finished the code also has taken the row number from sheet "SumGrupper" - where it has passed data (row holding "G1" in column A = **row number 5**), and replaced the word "SUM" from column A in sheet "NYlandSUM" with the value "5".
How the f... did that happen? Anyone that can spot what's wrong, and how to fix it?

Comment: Have you declared you variables?  Add `Option Explicit` at the very top of [every] module [always] to help ensure variables and objects are being properly declared and referenced.

Comment: `Range("S" & FoundRow & ":AE" & FoundRow).Copy`  should this be prefixed with a sheet reference?

Comment: Yes @ashleedawg , I'm using Option Explicit on this vba.

Comment: Just tried to change line to  `wb_rapp.Sheets(1).Range("S" & FoundRow & ":AE" & FoundRow).Copy`  but it did not fix my problem.